# Deploying Jenkins with Saltstack

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, vagrant, salt-stack, devops

So I started using Saltstack yesterday to install the packages for my Django project using https://github.com/wunki/django-salted/. You can probably imagine that I'm kinda lost, I don't really know how all of this works and the documentation is a bit vague, in my opinion. Can't find anything useful on installing and configuring Jenkins through Salt either, so I was wondering if anyone knew how to do it.

Comment: This question is probably a bit too broad for StackOverflow; that being said, there's an already-existing [Salt formula for deploying Jenkins](https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/jenkins-formula). You should be able to use it directly (see [the documentation on how to use formulas](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/development/conventions/formulas.html)) or at least use it as a source of inspiration.

Comment: It would be great to separate your questions on salt-django and salt-jenkins formulas - also if you could show us some code and errors you are getting into, we can be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

you can refer for jenkins installation through docker 
https://github.com/pratik141/salt_linux_packages/blob/master/jenkins.sls

Answer (score 0):

A simple state to deploy jenkins using embedded jetty container would look something like this

```
# deploy java
deploy-jdk:
  archive.extracted:
    - name: {{ java_install_path }}
    - source: salt://files/{{ jdk_tarball }}
    - archive_format: tar
    - if_missing: {{ java_install_path }}/bin/java

# deploy jenkins war
deploy-jenkins-war:
  file.managed:
    - name: {{ jenkins_install_path }}/jenkins.war
    - source: salt://files/jenkins.war
    - mode: 740

# start jenkins
cmd.run:
  - name: {{ java_install_path }}/bin/java -jar {{ jenkins_install_path }}/jenkins.war >/dev/null 2>&1
  - unless: jps | egrep -i 'jenkins.war'
  - order: last
```

If you'd like to manage jenkins configuration, you'd have to create the .jenkins directory in users home and add the config files in there using file.managed directive.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Jenkins formula. The final salt state would look like this.

CentOS/Redhat:

```
java-install:
  pkg.installed:
    - pkgs:
      - java-1.8.0-openjdk

include:
  - jenkins
```

Debian/Ubuntu:

```
java-install:
  pkg.installed:
    - pkgs:
      - openjdk-8-jre

include:
  - jenkins
```

Find full explanation here

CentOS/RedHat [>> https://www.easyaslinux.com/tutorials/devops/how-to-install-jenkins-in-centos-redhat-using-salt/](https://www.easyaslinux.com/tutorials/devops/how-to-install-jenkins-in-centos-redhat-using-salt/)

Ubuntu/Debian >> https://www.easyaslinux.com/tutorials/devops/how-to-install-jenkins-on-ubuntu-debian-using-salt/